# NLog is not logging anything

Tags: c#, nlog

Nlog won't protocol anything, although I have following files in my project:

[image]

NLog.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
  <!-- go to http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file for more information -->

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${basedir}/log/${shortdate}.log" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--
    Trace
    Debug
    Info
    Warn
    Error
    Fatal
    -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Following code should protocoll message in Debugmodus, but it doesn't do anything. I always will get message of Messagebox! Why? Of course, I'm running application  in Debug(Any CPU), not in Release mode

```
LogLevel level = LogLevel.Debug;
Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
_logger.IsEnabled(level);
if(!_logger.IsDebugEnabled && !_logger.IsErrorEnabled && !_logger.IsInfoEnabled) {
MessageBox.Show("Protocolation not activated!" + Environment.NewLine + "Abbruch");
}else
_logger.Debug("Protocol item has been written into logfile!");
```

ReEditing:
This is app.config looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what does your app.config file looks like?

Comment: Just redited my question. app.config has been published, now!

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but try inserting the text of the NLog.config into the app.config (under configuration node) (https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file)

Comment: Try to [configure debugging for NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging).

Comment: there is no configuration node in ur link! Apart from that, if I will change content of app.config, whole application will crash!

Comment: Enabling internal logging programmatically as having been shown in ur link won't protocol anything, too!

Comment: What is your app location (route)?

Comment: If U mean with app location route path to sln, here it is: D:\Visual Studio 2013\C#\WindowsForms\Vokabelprogramm-master. If U mean path to bin folder, here it is: D:\Visual Studio 2013\C#\WindowsForms\Vokabelprogramm-master\Vokabelprogramm\bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem, but got another one with Nlog.config. Following NLog.config will log, whatever I want to get logged:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
  <!-- go to http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file for more information -->

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="C:/Users/tklustig/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/C#/C#_GUI/Vokabelprogramm.git/log/${shortdate}.log" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--
    Trace
    Debug
    Info
    Warn
    Error
    Fatal
    -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

If I define filename like this:

```
fileName="${basedir}/log/${shortdate}.log"
```

there won't be logged anything! Why will NLog not accept $basedir? Is this invalid XML?

Comment: Have you tried looking a NLog Internal Logger output: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging